# Aspose mhtml export file size too large

Tags: size, aspose, mhtml

I have a document which contains a table only, if I use Aspose to export it in pdf and mhtml format separately, the mhtml file size is 10 times larger than pdf file size, any idea how to reduce the mhtml file size in Aspose export?

Here is the code:

```
var options = new HtmlSaveOptions(SaveFormat.Mhtml);
options.ExportHeadersFootersMode = ExportHeadersFootersMode.None;
document.Save(i_stream, options);
```

I also tried to add

```
options.CssStyleSheetType = CssStyleSheetType.Embedded;
```

but not working

Thanks!

---------------- More Info -------------------

Here is an example code I created:

```
var document = new Document();
            var builder = new DocumentBuilder(document);

            var table = builder.StartTable();

            for (var row = 0; row < 100; row++)
            {
                for (var column = 0; column < 100; column++)
                {
                    builder.InsertCell();
                    builder.Write("123");
                }

                builder.EndRow();
            }

            builder.EndTable();

            // export as PDF
            document.Save("c:\\temp\\test.pdf", SaveFormat.Pdf);

            // export as MHTML
            var options = new Aspose.Words.Saving.HtmlSaveOptions(SaveFormat.Mhtml);
            document.Save("c:\\temp\\test.mhtml", options);
```

The output shows the size for test.pdf file is 118k, but for test.mhtml is 5,070K

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please attach your input document here? I will investigate the issue and provide you more information. I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.

Comment: Hi Tahir, I added an example code to reproduce the issue, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Note that Aspose.Words mimics the same behavior as MS Word does. If you create a table with 100 rows and 63 columns in MS Word and save the document to mhtml, you will get the same output.

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.